# Pandas - select rows with best values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
   col1 col2 col3
0     2    A 1
1     1    A 100
2     3    B 12
3     4    B 2
```

I want to select the highest col1 value from all with A, then the one from all with B, etc, i.e. this is the desired output

```
   col1 col2  col3
0     2    A   1
3     4    B   2
```

I know I need some kind of groupby('col2'), but I don't know what to use after that.

Answer (score 3):

is that what you want?

```
In [16]: df.groupby('col2').max().reset_index()
Out[16]:
  col2  col1
0    A     2
1    B     4
```

Comment: @BaronYugovich, could you please update your input and desired data sets accordingly? so that it'll be clear...

Comment: please take a look at @piRSquareis's solution - IMO it's exactly what you need...

Answer (score 2):

use `groupby('col2')` then use `idxmax` to get the index of the max values within each group.  Finally, use these index values to slice the original dataframe.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('col2').col1.idxmax()]
```

[image]

Notice that the index values of the original dataframe are preserved.